# Bytecode version of ABI

Tags: abi

I wonder if aside the Json representation of ABI is there a bytecoded and compact version of the same interface. Json is human readable, but in some cases it is just an overkill.

Answer (score 1):

For some purposes it makes sense to have a more compact format of ABI, e.g. in the case you like to encode it as URL parameter like in this link of Ethereum Event Scan:

https://ethereum-event-scan-stg.cert4trust.de/?abi=eJylkzFPwzAQhf%2FLzZmQYMhaBpZuiKWK0NW5BkvuObLPCVHV%2F44DjZ20QlRhtP383b3n8%2B4EmtsgHspdVUCLA%2B4NQXlA46kALyi0DYJ7bbQMUAJbnkQFyNBGLSjLXlxQYh2cixNgFA1HG3zipBpjuZo%2BqZ4dCTlG8%2FrDwrp25H2EMx7HjXfbM7lcbBKMhf5gxaY0NxnVkfPacmZdBOcqSTbZyrPlmUfqiOXf7kJcPzw%2B5ZaUDRGbqkznd5i7DUo5wvEJ1kT1Cy1euKUt0hKHSjbX2pzW92xgXJQx1nlWmdKQJNAlDhtkFum6CO8a505Tn%2B8eAisZJ2TZ%2BfUz59aZ%2Bhf0H29oAm2RsSE3WVm4WP21ckfVF9GqRcY%3D&contract=0x73b69304Ea866a8d4baE183d8728BFf35AD4d19B&provider=https:%2F%2Fleopold-node3-rpc-stg.cert4trust.de&refresh=true&dark=true

The parameter api can be read with two steps:

1. decode base64
2. unzip

You may find an example implementation for encoding and decoding of the ABI in typescript [here](https://github.com/MarkusSprunck/ethereum-event-scan/blob/master/src/app/services/reader.service.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The general convention that people use is just to remove the white space on the JSON version of the ABI and put it all on one line if this helps.